# Remove random string between two string android

Tags: java, android

I want to remove some unnecessary links from a wiki page. Every link that I want to remove is start with `[<a href=` and ends with `]`. But at the same time there are also some references like `[1]`. I want to keep these references. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry My question was posted half because of stackoverflow formatting.

Comment: Please, give us two examples - one of just some link, another - with link containing references. Then it would be easier to give you a correct answer.

Comment: what you tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for this:

```
String cleanPage = wikiPage.replaceAll("\\[a href=.*?\\]", ""));
```